# javascript prototype method not defined

Tags: javascript

Im trying to become more object orientated in my approach to doing things and ive run into an error where the console says a function is undefined. I cant see how because i have other functions that run that have the same makeup.

i set up my object like this in my app.js:

```
var vid = new videoAPI(whichOs.type());
```

Then i set up my constructor in my lib.js:

```
function videoAPI(osParam)
{
    this.os = osParam;
}
```

And create my methods the one I have issues with is this one in my lib.js:

```
videoAPI.prototype.print = function()
{
    return this.os;
}
```

I then call in my app.js

```
console.log(print());
```

I have two other functions that use this setup but i pass variables in. 
Can anyone tell me what im doing wrong?

**edit.
The line it fails on is is print();
I didnt mention i have this in a node.js project linking two js files together. this is the error:

```
ReferenceError: print is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\denis\Desktop\videoServer\app.js:36:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

Comment: Please show the actual line of code that triggers the error.

Comment: Copying your code into the console and then calling `var vid = new videoAPI('A');` works with no errors.

Comment: seems you need `console.log(vid.print());`

Comment: Hmmm that works @Grundy but i have two other functions that dont need the prefix 'vid.' is there any reason why this needs it?

Comment: those two other functions probably exist globally off the window object.

Comment: @Seth, _at node.js:814:3_ in log, so seems this run not in a browser, but in node.js

Comment: Ahh, gotcha... then check the `global` object... not the `window` object.

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually call the method off of the `videoAPI` instance.

```
var vid = new videoAPI('something');
console.log(vid.print()) // returns: something
```

If you're calling other functions without prefixing them with the `videoAPI` instance variable, then they exist globally.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code provided, print is a prototype on the videoAPI object, but in the console log you're simply calling print.  Change:

```
console.log(print());
```

To:

```
console.log(vid.print());
```

It should fix your problem.

EDIT: Looks like Seth beat me to it :P